# How to configure JNDI Context in Axis2 under Tomcat 7?(JAX-WS web service that uses myBatis)

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis, jndi, mybatis

I realized a Java web service that runs on Axis2 (Jax-WS) under Tomcat 7.
To obtain data from postgreSQL this web service uses mybatis framework.
All works fine if I manually set the connection parameters in mybatis-config.xml but
I would like to use JNDI datasource to obtain them directly by the server context.

In the myBatis-config.xml I put the following tag (inside the environment tag):

```
<dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myWebService" />
</dataSource>
```

Searching on internet I also understood that I have to create a Tomcat (or Axis2 ?) Context whit the following tags:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myWebService" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB" username="user" password="password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

and

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>ConnectionToPostgreSQL</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myWebService</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

But I don't know where (in which xml file) I have to put them and if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Resource` definition can be defined in the `[your webapp name]/META-INF/context.xml` file, for example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="/[your webapp context]" privileged="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/myWebService" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB" username="user" password="password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

There's other options - such as defining it in the `server.xml` or shared `context`. See [JNDI Resources HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).

The `resource-ref` goes in your  `[your webapp name]/WEB-INF/web.xml`.